# Express routes: .get() requires callback functions but got a [object Object]

Tags: javascript, express

Ok, this should be easy for somebody to point out.

I checked the other similar questions and none helped.

I'm trying to move all my routes to a separate `routes.js` file. In it I have:

```
module.exports = function (app) {

  var user = {
      list : require('./routes/user.js')
    } 
  , index = {
      index : require('./routes/index.js')
    } 


  app.get('/', function(request, response){
    response.send('You made it to the home page.')
  });

  app.get('/users', user.list);
}
```

And in my `app.js` file I have this:

```
var register_routes = require('./routes.js')
register_routes(app)
```

My index route works fine, but it kicks back on `app.get('/users', user.list);` with this error:

> .get() requires callback functions but got a [object Object]

This is an out of the box express app so theres not too much to describe.

Thanks.

EDIT: Per request, here is what is in `./routes/user.js` :

```
exports.list = function(req, res){
  res.send("respond with a resource");
};
```

Comment: how does `./routes/user.js` look like?

Comment: Post the code in `'./routes/user.js'`, please. You need to export just a connect middleware function, but you are probably exporting a `setup` type function.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You export an object with the key `list` having the your function as value.

So to access your function you would need to do this `require('./routes/user.js').list`

Or with your code `user.list.list`.

To solve this you have two possibilities.

Either write:

```
var user = {
  list : require('./routes/user.js').list
}
```

Or:

```
module.exports = function(req, res){
   res.send("respond with a resource");
};
```

**EDIT**

If your `routes/user.js` will probably later look like this:

```
module.exports.list = function(req, res){
   res.send("respond with a resource");
};

module.exports.delete = function(req, res){
   res.send("delete user");
};
```

If yes then you can just write it that way in your `routes.js`:

```
var user = require('./routes/user.js');
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is:

```
module.exports = function (app) {

  var user = {
      list : function(request, response){  
                    require('./routes/user.js');
            } 
}
    } 
  , index = {
      index : function(request, response){ 
          require('./routes/index.js') 
        }
    } 


  app.get('/', function(request, response){
    response.send('You made it to the home page.')
  });

  app.get('/users', user.list);
}
```

In this way give a callback to the route and this callback execute the require.

Comment: And how should `request`, `response` then be called within `./routes/user.js`? `require('./routes/user.js');` just includes the file then but does not call the _routing code_. This way the request will timeout without doing anything.

Comment: Yeah, its a step forward. It doesnt error out anymore, but it eventually times out and does nothing

Comment: In this case we are trying make muti-routes file. We need add "more specific" routes into ./routes/user.js.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **router** in your application for all routing purpose,

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var index = require('./index');


/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', index.list);

module.exports = router;
```

then in your index.js file, just do

```
router.list = function(req, res){
   res.send("respond with a resource"); 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

After so many time seeking around in web, I found something.

First of all, You instantiate the code like this on another file, (e.g.: humancomms.ts):

```
import express from 'express';

export function shout(request: express.Request, response: express.Response, next: () => void) {
    response.send('Shout so loud!');
}

export function speak(request: express.Request, response: express.Response, next: () => void) {
    response.send('Speak less loud!');
}
```

What exactly this code does? Nobody knows.(Hehe, just kiddin')

This make a middleware functions to separate from main server file to... organize, of course.

And how We can use it? Just like this (inside your server file):

```
const shout = require('./humancomms').shout;
const speak = require('./humancomms').speak;

app.use('/shout', shout);
app.use('/speak', speak);
```

This code takes all middlewares funcs and executes when some path is called.

This not solve all problems like multi path to same type, as if You want call differently intensities of shout ('/shout/high?asd=asd', '/shout/low?asd=asd'), but there is a catch You can try on secondary file:

```
import express from 'express';

export function shout(request: express.Request, response: express.Response, next: () => void) {

    if (request.path.includes('/high')) {
        response.send('Shout so loud!');
    } else if (request.path.includes('/low')) {
        response.send('Really shout?');
    }
}
```

Look at this good article about:

TypeScript Express tutorial #1. Middleware, routing, and controllers (https://wanago.io/2018/12/03/typescript-express-tutorial-routing-controllers-middleware/)

and the official documentation website:

Writing middleware for use in Express apps (http://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html)