# Route.all() requires callback functions but got a [object String])=> then showing 404 errros

Tags: node.js, express

I have recently started to look at node Js, my question is about express routing.

I have a dishRouter.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var dishRouter = express.Router();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
dishRouter.use(bodyParser.json());

dishRouter   //.route('/dishes')
.all('/dishes', function(req, res, next){
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        next();
})
.get('/dishes', function(req, res, next){
    res.end('will send all dishes to you');
})
.get('/dishes/:dishId', function(req, res, next){
    res.end('will send the dish '+ req.params.dishId + ' to you');
})
.post('/dishes', function(req, res, next){
    res.end('will add  the dish '+ req.body.name + ' with details ' + req.body.description);
})
.put('/dishes/:dishId', function(req, res, next){
    res.write('Updating the dish '+ req.params.dishId+ ' ');
    res.end(' Updating the dish '+ req.body.name + ' with details '+ req.body.description);
})
.delete('/dishes', function(req, res, next){
    res.end('Deleteing all dishes');
})
.delete('/dishes/:dishId', function(req, res, next){
    res.end('Deleteing the dish '+ req.params.dishId);
});

module.exports = dishRouter;
```

And server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var host ='localhost';
var port = 3000;
var app = express();
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/dishes', require('./dishRouter'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.listen(port,host,function(){
    console.log(`Server running at http://${host}:${port}`);
});
```

In a single file, it worked fine, but when I try to separate them out like above, it doesn't work, and now My terminal shows me this error:

```
Route.all() requires callback functions but got a [object String]
```

What am I doing wrong, please?

## Update: 30.08.16 @ 23:38

I managed to fix the error at the terminal by NOT chaining .all() to .route()
so I`m doing this now:

```
dishRouter.route('/dishes');

dishRouter.all('/dishes', function(req, res, next){
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        next();
})
.get('/dishes', function(req, res, next){
    res.end('will send all dishes to you');
})
.get('/dishes/:dishId', function(req, res, next){
    res.end('will send the dish '+ req.params.dishId + ' to you');
}) 
   // ......... the rest as before..........
```

BUT: now i get 404 for all methods(get, post,put,delete):

```
        Server running at http://localhost:3000
        DELETE /dishes/0 404 219.103 ms - 24
        GET /dishes/0 404 22.813 ms - 21
        GET /dishes/ 404 1.743 ms - 20
        GET / 200 7.699 ms - 130
        GET /leaders 404 30.800 ms - 20
        GET /leader 404 0.591 ms - 19
        PUT /leaders/1 404 1.616 ms - 22
        PUT /dishes/1 404 0.595 ms - 21
        PUT /dishes/1 404 0.847 ms - 21
        GET /dishes/1 404 0.857 ms - 21
        GET /dishes 404 1.082 ms - 19
        POST /dishes 404 0.679 ms - 20
        POST /dishes 404 0.901 ms - 20
        GET /dishes 404 2.847 ms - 19
        POST /dishes 404 0.671 ms - 20
```

any idea what is wrong now? thank you..

## Update on: 31/08/2016 @ 06:28am

I managed to retrieve the data, my mistake was using dishRouter.route('/dishes'); dishRouter.all('/dishes') ..... and so on.

now im doing  dishRouter.route('/dishes'); dishRouter.all(/)  ... and for params: dishRouter.get(/:dishId)  .. and so on.

so here  is my final file dishRouter.js:

```
    var express = require('express');
var dishRouter = express.Router();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
dishRouter.use(bodyParser.json());

dishRouter.route('/dishes');

dishRouter.all('/', function(req, res, next){
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        next();
})
.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.end('will send all dishes to you');
})
.get('/:dishId', function(req, res){
    res.end('will send the dish ('+ req.params.dishId + ') to you');
})
.post('/', function(req, res){
    res.end('will add  the dish ('+ req.body.name + ') with details (' + req.body.description + 'about the dish)');
})
.put('/:dishId', function(req, res){
    res.write('Updating the dish ('+ req.params.dishId+ ')');
    res.end(' Updating the dish ('+ req.body.name + ') with details ('+ req.body.description + 'about the dish)');
})
.delete('/', function(req, res){
    res.end('Deleteing all dishes');
})
.delete('/:dishId', function(req, res){
    res.end('Deleteing the dish ('+ req.params.dishId + ')');
});

module.exports = dishRouter;
```

## update: 05/09/2016 @ 12:30pm:

that solution above worked just fine,, 
but I find out that there is a better way to structure the router file , I have found that through the tutorial i have been following which called (Server-side Development with NodeJS) on coursera website.

ill post that final file as an answer below for benefit of all.

Thanks again to everybody.

Comment: @brandonscript, How can i accept ur edit? just copy-paste it?

Comment: I have enough reputation that you don't need to approve it, but feel free to clear up the code snippets - you've got quite a bit of duplicated code in there, and it's hard to tell for sure what your setup looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the best practice to solve this issue, although the above updates of my question sorted everything out but the below file looks better and more readable, so here is the final dishRoute.js

```
var express = require('express');
var dishRouter = express.Router();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
dishRouter.use(bodyParser.json());

dishRouter.route('/')
.all(function(req, res, next){
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        next();
})
.get(function(req, res){
    res.end('will send all dishes to you');
})

.post(function(req, res){
    res.end('will add  the dish ('+ req.body.name + ') with details (' + req.body.description + 'about the dish)');
})
.put(function(req, res){
    res.write('Updating the dish ('+ req.params.dishId+ ')');
    res.end(' Updating the dish ('+ req.body.name + ') with details ('+ req.body.description + 'about the dish)');
})
.delete(function(req, res){
    res.end('Deleteing all dishes');
});

dishRouter.route('/:dishId')
.all(function(req, res, next){
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        next();
})
.get(function(req, res){
    res.end('will send the dish ('+ req.params.dishId + ') to you');
})
.put(function(req, res){
    res.write('Updating the dish ('+ req.params.dishId+ ')');
    res.end(' Updating the dish ('+ req.body.name + ') with details ('+ req.body.description + 'about the dish)');
})
.delete(function(req, res){
    res.end('Deleteing the dish ('+ req.params.dishId + ')');
});

module.exports = dishRouter;
```

note: the server.js file still the same as in the question above.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you have tried this already, but res.end() is used to quickly end the response without any data. Your error may be caused by using that, coupled with attempting to pass data to it, as you are doing.

You could try combining your res.write and res.end by using the res.send() method, which works in a similar way to res.end() except for the fact that you can pass data back in the response.

Read more [here](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.end)

Comment: Gives exactly same result!

Comment: It may be because you are exporting an an object from your routes file. Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21124909/express-routes-get-requires-callback-functions-but-got-a-object-object

Comment: Thank you for ur effors, appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

According to the error, it has something to do with that [`.all()`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#router.all) method. Not sure about that, but your problem of breaking the files apart may come from the fact that you've declared nested paths.

```
var dishRouter = express.Router();
dishRouter.use(bodyParser.json());

dishRouter.route('/dishes')
.get('/dishes', function(req, res, next){
    res.end('will send all dishes to you');
});

module.exports = dishRouter;
```

And then

```
app.use('/dishes', require('./dishRouter'));
```

You've essentially set the path of those routes at `/dishes/dishes`, which I'm getting you don't want.

If you instead want to have the path at `/dishes`, keep the `app.use` line, but change the `router` like this

```
var dishRouter = express.Router();
dishRouter.use(bodyParser.json());

dishRouter.get('/', function(req, res, next){
    res.end('will send all dishes to you');
});

module.exports = dishRouter;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you gave me a great hint so i voted u up, the only reason that i couldn`t accept the answer is that i want people in my situation to know the solution i acheived by keeping ,route()  and  .all() methods. highly appreciated.

Comment: I had a mistake in my answer, anyways. Glad you figured it out. You should answer down here instead of updating the question with the solution, though