# Separating Express.js-Routes into separate Files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, coffeescript

I'm using **express.js** and am trying to separate my routes in a separate file.

This is an excerpt from my **./app.coffee**:

```
viewsRouter = express.Router()

routesCallingViews = require('./app/routes/callingViews')

app.use '/', routesCallingViews.showApp viewsRouter, user, data
app.use '/', routesCallingViews.showSignUpForm viewsRouter
app.use '/', routesCallingViews.showLogInForm viewsRouter
```

the **./app/routes/callingViews** looks like:

```
module.exports =

  showApp: (router, user, data) ->
    router.get '/', user.isSignedIn, (req, res) ->
      ...

  showSignUpForm: (router) ->
    router.get '/signup', (req, res) ->
      ...

  showLogInForm: (router) ->
    router.get '/login', (req, res) ->
      ...
```

I get this error:

```
Error: Route.get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: follow this link it may help you and let me know if any problem or getting same error
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21124909/express-routes-get-requires-callback-functions-but-got-a-object-object

Answer (score 0):

Common way to do what you are trying would be to extract all related routes to separate module where you would create and export instance of router, something like:

```
// foo.js
'use strict'

const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => { ... })
router.post('/bar', (req, res, next) => { ... })
...

module.exports = router
```

Then from whatever place (usually from `server.js`) you would hook all routers that you have, something like:

```
const fooRoutes = require('./foo')
app.use('/foo', fooRoutes)
```

So you will end up with:

```
GET /foo
POST /foo/bar
```