# Route.get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined] after modifying server routes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, mongoose

**CODE:**

server routes

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies
 */
var articlesPolicy = require('../policies/articles.server.policy'),
  articles = require('../controllers/articles.server.controller');

module.exports = function (app) {
  // Articles collection routes
  app.route('/api/articles').all(articlesPolicy.isAllowed)
    .get(articles.list)
    .post(articles.create);

  // Own articles collection routes
  app.route('/api/articles/myarticles').all(articlesPolicy.isAllowed)
    .get(articles.mylist)
    .delete(articles.delete);

  // Single article routes
  app.route('/api/articles/:articleId').all(articlesPolicy.isAllowed)
    .get(articles.read)
    .put(articles.update)
    .delete(articles.delete);

  // Finish by binding the article middleware
  app.param('articleId', articles.articleByID);
};
```

Controller

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies
 */
var path = require('path'),
  mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Article = mongoose.model('Article'),
  errorHandler = require(path.resolve('./modules/core/server/controllers/errors.server.controller'));

/**
 * Create an article
 */
exports.create = function (req, res) {
  var article = new Article(req.body);
  article.user = req.user;

  article.save(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(422).send({
        message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
      });
    } else {
      res.json(article);
    }
  });
};

/**
 * Show the current article
 */
exports.read = function (req, res) {
  // convert mongoose document to JSON
  var article = req.article ? req.article.toJSON() : {};

  // Add a custom field to the Article, for determining if the current User is the "owner".
  // NOTE: This field is NOT persisted to the database, since it doesn't exist in the Article model.
  article.isCurrentUserOwner = !!(req.user && article.user && article.user._id.toString() === req.user._id.toString());

  res.json(article);
};

/**
 * Update an article
 */
exports.update = function (req, res) {
  var article = req.article;

  article.title = req.body.title;
  article.content = req.body.content;

  article.save(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(422).send({
        message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
      });
    } else {
      res.json(article);
    }
  });
};

/**
 * Delete an article
 */
exports.delete = function (req, res) {
  var article = req.article;

  article.remove(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(422).send({
        message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
      });
    } else {
      res.json(article);
    }
  });
};

/**
 * List of Articles
 */
exports.list = function (req, res) {
  Article.find().sort('-created').populate('user', 'displayName').exec(function (err, articles) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(422).send({
        message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
      });
    } else {
      res.json(articles);
    }
  });
};

/**
 * List of own Articles
 */
exports.myList = function (req, res) {
  Article.find({ user: req.user._id.toString() }).sort('-created').populate('user', 'displayName').exec(function (err, articles) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(422).send({
        message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
      });
    } else {
      res.json(articles);
    }
  });
};

/**
 * Article middleware
 */
exports.articleByID = function (req, res, next, id) {

  if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)) {
    return res.status(400).send({
      message: 'Article is invalid'
    });
  }

  Article.findById(id).populate('user', 'displayName').exec(function (err, article) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    } else if (!article) {
      return res.status(404).send({
        message: 'No article with that identifier has been found'
      });
    }
    req.article = article;
    next();
  });
};
```

Server Policy

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies
 */
var acl = require('acl');

// Using the memory backend
acl = new acl(new acl.memoryBackend());

/**
 * Invoke Articles Permissions
 */
exports.invokeRolesPolicies = function () {
  acl.allow([{
    roles: ['admin'],
    allows: [{
      resources: '/api/articles',
      permissions: '*'
    }, {
      resources: '/api/articles/:articleId',
      permissions: '*'
    }, {
      resources: '/api/articles/create',
      permissions: '*'
    }]
  }, {
    roles: ['user'],
    allows: [{
      resources: '/api/articles',
      permissions: ['get']
    }, {
      resources: '/api/articles/:articleId',
      permissions: ['get']
    }, {
      resources: '/api/articles/create',
      permissions: '*'
    }, {
      resources: '/api/myarticles/',
      permissions: '*'
    }]
  }, {
    roles: ['guest'],
    allows: [{
      resources: '/api/articles',
      permissions: ['get']
    }, {
      resources: '/api/articles/:articleId',
      permissions: ['get']
    }]
  }]);
};

/**
 * Check If Articles Policy Allows
 */
exports.isAllowed = function (req, res, next) {
  var roles = (req.user) ? req.user.roles : ['guest'];

  // If an article is being processed and the current user created it then allow any manipulation
  if (req.article && req.user && req.article.user && req.article.user.id === req.user.id) {
    return next();
  }

  // Check for user roles
  acl.areAnyRolesAllowed(roles, req.route.path, req.method.toLowerCase(), function (err, isAllowed) {
    if (err) {
      // An authorization error occurred
      return res.status(500).send('Unexpected authorization error');
    } else {
      if (isAllowed) {
        // Access granted! Invoke next middleware
        return next();
      } else {
        return res.status(403).json({
          message: 'User is not authorized'
        });
      }
    }
  });
};
```

---

**SITUATION:**

I added app.route('/api/articles/myarticles') to my server routes.

Immediately, I get the following error in my terminal:

Route.get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]
    at Route.(anonymous function) [as get]

---

**QUESTION:**

What have I done wrong and how do I fix it ?

---

**WHAT I LOOKED AT:**

[Express routes: .get() requires callback functions but got a [object Object]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21124909/express-routes-get-requires-callback-functions-but-got-a-object-object)

I must have declared something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a simple typo error. You have `articles.mylist` instead of `articles.myList`:

```
app.route('/api/articles/myarticles').all(articlesPolicy.isAllowed)
    .get(articles.myList)  // <--- it should be myList instead of mylist
    .delete(articles.delete);
```

Comment: I see. But that still does not fix the issue :/ Now articles.list is used instead of myList. Could you please have a look at my edit ?

Comment: Are you sure you are still not making any typo error and you have typed `articles.myList` correctly? Check spelling & case.

Comment: Yes, I think the ArticleSevice is the issue ? It's the one used for list and I just reused it for myList, does it make a difference ?

Comment: Try changing the sequence of the routes. Move the first one `app.route('/api/articles')` to the end.

Comment: What is the error message? How did you check it is going to `articles.list` and not to `articles.myList`

Comment: I can see it, because I can navigate to articles/myarticles on my website and all the articles are shown instead of just my own.

Comment: Thats not the right way to check. It is possible that the query inside `articles.myList` is returning all the articles. Put a `console.log` inside `articles.myList` to check if the code is actually going into that method.

Comment: I know it is working because I also tried replacing articles.list with articles.myList's code and it worked as I wanted.

Comment: But I need both of them

Comment: Problem is articles/myarticles is using articles.list instead of articles.myList

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134845/discussion-between-santanu-biswas-and-coder1000).