# Route.connect() requires a callback function but got a [object Object]

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

This error is coming whenever i try to start my website..i have installed all dependencies..but still this error comes
   /workspace/Back_end_ethics/corona/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:202
            throw new Error(msg);
            ^

```
Error: Route.connect() requires a callback function but got a [object Object]
    at Route.(anonymous function) [as connect] (/workspace/Back_end_ethics/corona/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:202:15)
    at Function.app.(anonymous function) [as connect] (/workspace/Back_end_ethics/corona/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:482:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/workspace/Back_end_ethics/corona/app.js:14:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
```

**App.js**
This is the main app.js file

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var passport = require("passport");
var localStrategy = require("passport-local");
var flash = require("connect-flash");
//var methodOverride = require("method-override");
var authRoutes = require("./routes/auth");
var covidRoutes = require("./routes/Covid");
var User = require("./models/user");
var Update = require("./models/update");

app.connect("mongodb://localhost/corona",{
    useNewUrlParser:true,
    useUnifiedTopology:true
});

app.set("view engine","ejs");
app.use(express.static(__dirname+"/public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(flash());

//PASSPORT CONFIG
app.use(require("express-session")({
        secret:"Once again Rusty wins cute dog",
        resave:false,
        saveUninitialized:false
        }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

app.use(function(req,res,next){
    res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
    res.locals.error = req.flash("error");
    res.locals.success = req.flash("success");
    next();
});

app.use(authRoutes);
app.use(covidRoutes);


//ROUTES
app.get("/charts",function(req,res){
    res.render("charts");
});

app.get("/new",function(req,res){
    res.render("new");
});

app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("Server is Started!");
});
```

**models/update.js**
This is the schema for the Updates

```
    var mongoose = require("mongoose");

    var updateSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        created_at:{type: Date, default: Date.now},
        link:String,
        heading:String
    });

    module.exports = mongoose.model("Update",updateSchema);
```

**models/user.js**
This is the schema for the user

```
    var mongoose = require("mongoose");
    var passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

    var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        username:String,
        password:String
    });

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User",userSchema);
```

**routes/auth.js**
This is routes for the authorization i.e Login,Register

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router({mergeParams:true});
var passport = require("passport");
var User = require("../models/user");

router.get("/register",function(req,res){
    res.render("Auth/register",{page:"register"});
});

router.post("register",function(req,res){
    var newUser = new User({username:req.body.username});
    User.register(newUser,req.body.password,function(err,User){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            return res.render("Auth/register",{err:err.message});
        }
        passport.authenticate("local")(req,res,function(){
            res.redirect("/new");
        });
    });
});

router.get("/login",function(req,res){
    res.render("Auth/login",{page:"login"});
});

router.post("/login",passport.authenticate("local",{
    successRedirect:"/new",
    failureRedirect:"Auth/login"
}),function(req,res){   
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Express routes: .get() requires callback functions but got a \[object Object\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21124909/express-routes-get-requires-callback-functions-but-got-a-object-object)

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your code with something like that:

Either write:

```
var user = {
  list : require('./routes/user.js').list
}
```

Or:

```
module.exports = function(req, res){
   res.send("respond with a resource");
};
```

**EDIT**

If your `routes/user.js` will probably later look like this:

```
module.exports.list = function(req, res){
   res.send("respond with a resource");
};

module.exports.delete = function(req, res){
   res.send("delete user");
};
```

If yes then you can just write it that way in your `routes.js`:

```
var user = require('./routes/user.js');
```