# Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Object]

Tags: node.js, express, middleware, jwt

I'm working through a MERN app.

> MERN?
>
> - MongoDB: Database
> - Express: Middleware
> - React.js: Frontend
> - Node.js: Backend

But while token authentication I'm getting following error:

`Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Object]`

This is my express code

```js
router.get('/', userTokenAuth,async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const user = await User.findById(req.user.id).select('-password');
        res.json({
            data: user
        })
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({
            error
        })
    }
})
```

This is authentication code

```js
require('dotenv/config');
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

module.export = (req, res, next) => {
    const header = req.header('token');
    if(header){
        const decoded = jwt.verify(
            token,
            process.env.TOKEN,
            (err, user) => {
                if(err) return res.sendStatus(403);                
                console.log(decoded)
                req.user = decoded.user
                next();
            }
        )
    }else{
        res.status(404);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21124909/express-routes-get-requires-callback-functions-but-got-a-object-object/21125097

Comment: I think your export is wrong, it should be `module.exports`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is probably that your auth function is incorrectly exported.

Try changing `module.export` to `module.exports`

Comment: yes ... but still I'm not getting any response. it is only sending request non-stop.

Comment: That's probably another issue. Open a new SO question for it.